# VB.NET If (ternary) bug

Tags: vb.net

I found a simple bug in VB.NET that can be easily reproduced:

```
Dim pDate As Date?
Dim pString As String = ""

' works fine as expected
pDate = If(False, "", Nothing) 

' expected: pDate will be set to Nothing. 
' BUG: Conversion from string "" to type 'Date' is not valid.
pDate = If(False, pString, Nothing) 

'These both fail with the same error
pDate = pString
Dim pDate2 As Date? = ""
```

Question: Is this a bug? Or is there something wrong with me or my PC? 
If this is a bug, is there a bug report of this (I cant seem to find it)?

Lessons learned:

1. this is not a bug
2. nullable date accepts object nothing
3. nullable date rejects string nothing

---

```
pDate = Nothing ' ok. nullable date accepts object nothing
pString = Nothing
pDate = pString ' error. nullable date rejects string nothing
```

Comment: How is that a bug? You *can't* convert `""` to a `Date`. Even though `If` (as opposed to `IIf`) evaluates only one side at run time doesn't mean the compiler doesn't detect type mismatches.

Comment: Yes, I understand that the compiler still detect type mismatches but how come that (pDate = "") is valid while (pDate = pString) is not even though (pString = "")

Comment: pDate = "" is not valid if Option Strict or Option Infer are on.

Comment: @Arvin It is not a bug. The fact is "implicit" conversion take place. Set **Option Strict On** and see what happen.

Comment: @adatapost: If strict is off, can it do the conversion on non-empty strings?

Comment: Fixed your formatting: you just have to indent a little more

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The bug is in your first use of `If()`, not the second.  Contrary to your comment, the result there is not "expected".  That call *should* fail, because "" cannot convert to a date and the ternary operator is typesafe at all levels whether or not the expression is used.

I suspect it succeeds because of a compiler optimization: since everything is all literals, the condition is optimized away. It's harder to make the optimization the second time, because the pString variable might be changed by another thread the compiler doesn't know about yet.

Someone who's handier with IL can probably confirm this.

The real surprise for me is that this is not caught until runtime. I would expect the compiler to notice the type mismatch and complain at that level, rather than waiting until execution.  Your VB Option settings may have something to do with that.

Comment: Most likely what happens is that the constant folding happens before type checking. The first expression is evaluated as a constant before the types are checked. Since `pString` is not a constant, it can't be optimized out without data flow analysis which takes place after type checking.

Comment: 4th lesson learned: "ternary operator is typesafe at all levels whether or not the expression is used."

Answer (score 3):

This is pretty interesting.  The example above is pretty clear that there is something odd going on.  That said, Stack Overflow isn't really a good place to "report" bugs.  If you think you have really found a bug you can post your findings to [Microsoft connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/CreateFeedback.aspx).

I did a search on connect and there are quite a few quirks with both the VB.NET and C# ternary operator, especially when Nullable value types are involved.  This just may be another one of them?

For what it's worth, you can even simplify the case to look like:

```
Dim pDate As Date?
pDate = If(False, "", Nothing) ' Works fine
pDate = If(False, String.Empty, Nothing) ' Doesn't work
```

It is worth noting that every situation that appears to be broken (all cases expect usage of `""`) *does work* when the line looks like: `pDate = If(False, String.Empty, CType(Nothing, Date?))`

Also, `Option Strict [On|Off]` plays a very big role in this.  When `Option Strict On` is set, then all of these are compile errors.  This behavior can only be seen when `Option Strict Off`.  I've put together [an example of all the situations here](http://rextester.com/rundotnet?code=MHFCVT90817).

In the end, I don't think this is really a bug, but simply one of the pitfalls of using `Option Strict Off`.  It does seem odd (illogical), but then again so does having `Option Strict Off`. ;)

Comment: By default Option Strict is off in VB, that's the only reason why anything weird is going on here. If it was on, both lines would (or should) throw compiler errors.